# deleting vector of empty unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, memory-leaks, unique-ptr

I've encountered a problem with memory leak when I try to make a vector of unique_ptr. I've tried to find where is the problem and I finally end up with this (meaningless) piece of code (my code contains meaningful operations, here are integers for simplicity):

```
class Deleter
{
public:

    void operator()(int* ptr)
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
};
```

and

```
vector<unique_ptr<int, Deleter>> data;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    int* temp = NULL;
    unique_ptr<int, Deleter> uptr;
    uptr = unique_ptr<int, Deleter>(temp);

    data.push_back(move(uptr));
    uptr.~unique_ptr();
}

data.~vector();
```

This code makes a small memory leak, but I am curious where is the problem, thanks

Comment: The whole point of `std::unique_ptr` is that you usually don't do the memory mangagment yourself. What is the purpose of that cod actually?

Comment: Your explicit destruction makes the code undefined. Where did you get the idea that you should call the destructor?

Comment: don't call destructors manually, don't assign `NULL` to `unique_ptr` (they start initialized with nullptr)

Comment: I need to destroy a vector of pointers to bitmaps in library Allegro. However, for deletion of them there should be call a function al_delete_bitmap(pointer to bitmap), and this is in the deleter funkcion. After I delete all bitmaps, some small memory space is left behind and I figured out that the same space is left even if I use integers instead of bitmaps, co there isn't problem of bitmaps but of my code. In the original code there isn't any NULL, but actual pointer to somewhere, it is there if I forgot to do something with temp or whatever :)

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `uptr.~unique_ptr();` or `data.~vector();` were needed or useful to begin with? Your understanding of C++ object lifetime appears to be significantly off. Reading a good C++ book should help fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is it possible that you get a memory leak if you don't allocate memory in this code? Stop calling destructors manually, it should fix the leak.

Note: even if you specify the `Deleter` type, you are not passing an instance of it, just using the default constructor inside.

```
#include <memory>

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int, Deleter>> data;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    data.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int, Deleter>(new int(i)));
}
```

Example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Kg4XfhwkwxSILwq3

Comment: Good advice, but I'm not sure this answers the question.

Comment: A default constructed deleter should be fine here, particularly because the class contains no state.

Comment: I assigned NULL just becouse I wanted to show it doesn't matter if I actually put something in or not, in my actual code there is never NULL.

Comment: I tried the line you suggest, but the compiler tells me that it is wrong...

Comment: E0304 -> No instance of function overload  "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [where _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int, Deleter>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int, Deleter>>]" doesn't match the list of arguments

Comment: You can't use `std::make_unique` to make a unique_ptr with a custom deleter. The template arguments after the first are variadic and meant to be deduced from the runtime arguments and then forwarded to the constructor of whatever the first type is.

Comment: However I can't use new on the data type I'm working with, it is created specifically by calling al_load_bitmap(const char* fileName)

Comment: @JuanCarlos then replace the `new int(i)` with `al_load_bitmap(whatever)`. Why do you give us an incorrect example that doesn't match your "real-world" code?

Comment: Sorry I thought I would make it more clear if there wouldn't be anything from  specific c/c++ library (Allegro). As I see it made more confusion than if I copy-pasted it from my code...